# Creating bigrams list not in list of tuples but in list of strings of both words combined

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using this code to create bigrams for tokenization of a list of titles (headlines).

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
def bigram_creator(headlines):
    bigrams = []
    for line in headlines:
        bigrm = nltk.bigrams(line.split())
        bigrams.extend(bigrm)
    return bigrams
```

However the code is giving me a list of tuples:

ex: [('opinion', 'one'), ('one', 'good')]

and I would like it to output a list of strings of both words together:

ex[('opinion one'), ('one good')]

Anybody know what I have to do to my code to change it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `' '.join()`. Also, your output will not have the tuples, though I'd say they are unesassary.

```
bad_output = [('opinion', 'one'), ('one', 'good')]
good_output = [' '.join(tup) for tup in bad_output]
```

output

```
['opinion one', 'one good']
```

Comment: Thank You!!! This code works but it is taking way to long to iterate through the enitre dataset. Any faster approaches?

Comment: does every tuple have only two elements?

Comment: Yes they are bigrams

Comment: . No clue what that is but. ok try this `good_output = [tup[0]+' '+tup[1] for tup in bad_output]`